# Unique URL for each image (preferably with only a hash appended) which shows the popup image directly

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup, zepto

I'm using the Magnific popup script.

The script is great, but what I'm missing is that the URL (www.mysite.com/?rel=gallery) is not changing, regardless of which image is shown in the popup, so nobody can link to my one image directly, just to my whole gallery.

It would be great if every image would append a unique hash (#mypic1 etc., preferably grabbed from the id of the image or its wrapper) to the URL. It should be only a hash so the site is not reloaded each time when browsing the gallery itself.

This unique URL (www.mysite.com/?rel=gallery#mypic1), if linked to from an external site, of course, should open the popup with the image#mypic1 directly.

Comment: You need to tell us what library you use for the pop-up.

Comment: I guess it's magnific-popup, as mentionned as a tag. Not clear, I admit. - http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/

Comment: My apologies for not making that clear.  I saw an earlier user with my exact question and attached a bonus.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the code:

```
$('.image-link').magnificPopup({
    ...
    ...
    callbacks: {
        elementParse: function(item) {
            // Function will fire for each target element
            // "item.el" is a target DOM element (if present)
            // "item.src" is a source that you may modify
            window.location.hash = item.src;
        }
    }
});
```

`window.location.hash` will write "#something" in the URL and it won't reload the page.
You can write whatever you want in the `hash`.

If you're using PHP, you would catch the hash using the following code:

```
<?php 
$url = "";
$parsed_url = parse_url($url);
$hash = isset($parsed_url['fragment']) ? $parsed_url['fragment'] : '';
?>
```

Comment: Awesome, this was the clue I was seeking. Had actually read that part of the doc but the phrase "to parse the source..." threw me off.

Comment: Then adding the line `$('a[href="'+window.location.hash.substr(1)+'"').trigger('click')` will trigger the popup that generated the hash when the page is reloaded.

Comment: Exactly :)
Keep in mind that you should have any event binded to this HTML element. Otherwise, you'll have a "bubble" effect.